# AWS Lambda using Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am just trying to use Visual Studio Code to work on AWS lambda function and following steps in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dotnet-coreclr-deployment-package.html) link

After following all steps when I run dotnet lambda I keep getting following error. My all packages are up to date and also I am using core 2.1

```
PS C:\Lambda> dotnet lambda --help
No executable found matching command "dotnet-lambda"
```

**My Project File:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is my project structure look like which was created by the template

[image]

VS Code version

[image]

Also when I run dotnet --help I don't even see dotnet lambda in sdk

```
dotnet --help
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.403)
Usage: dotnet [runtime-options] [path-to-application] [arguments]

Execute a .NET Core application.

runtime-options:
  --additionalprobingpath <path>     Path containing probing policy and assemblies to probe for.
  --additional-deps <path>           Path to additional deps.json file.
  --fx-version <version>             Version of the installed Shared Framework to use to run the application.
  --roll-forward-on-no-candidate-fx  Roll forward on no candidate shared framework is enabled.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.

Usage: dotnet [sdk-options] [command] [command-options] [arguments]

Execute a .NET Core SDK command.

sdk-options:
  -d|--diagnostics  Enable diagnostic output.
  -h|--help         Show command line help.
  --info            Display .NET Core information.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --version         Display .NET Core SDK version in use.

SDK commands:
  add               Add a package or reference to a .NET project.
  build             Build a .NET project.
  build-server      Interact with servers started by a build.
  clean             Clean build outputs of a .NET project.
  help              Show command line help.
  list              List project references of a .NET project.
  migrate           Migrate a project.json project to an MSBuild project.
  msbuild           Run Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild) commands.
  new               Create a new .NET project or file.
  nuget             Provides additional NuGet commands.
  pack              Create a NuGet package.
  publish           Publish a .NET project for deployment.
  remove            Remove a package or reference from a .NET project.
  restore           Restore dependencies specified in a .NET project.
  run               Build and run a .NET project output.
  sln               Modify Visual Studio solution files.
  store             Store the specified assemblies in the runtime package store.
  test              Run unit tests using the test runner specified in a .NET project.
  tool              Install or manage tools that extend the .NET experience.
  vstest            Run Microsoft Test Engine (VSTest) commands.

Additional commands from bundled tools:
  dev-certs         Create and manage development certificates.
  ef                Entity Framework Core command-line tools.
  sql-cache         SQL Server cache command-line tools.
  user-secrets      Manage development user secrets.
  watch             Start a file watcher that runs a command when files change.

Run 'dotnet [command] --help' for more information on a command.
```

Can someone please guide me

Thanks

Comment: Install Amazon Lambda Tools `dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools`

Comment: dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
Tool 'amazon.lambda.tools' is already installed.

Comment: and still nothing for `dotnet lambda`? check that the folder containing the tools is in your $PATH.

Comment: Yes still same I have already installed lambda tools before I started this project

Comment: same issue here, could you resolve this somehow?. thanks.

Comment: i could resolve it by restarting VS code...

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue, 
[image: No executable found matching command "dotnet-lambda"]

and below is my fix

```
dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 3.1.2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS Code after running

```
dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```

Worked for me

Comment: Is this not what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54452434/1364007) suggested?

Comment: I feel the part about restarting VS Code was relevant as the solution will not work without that step, however I was unable to comment due to reputation requirements.